# Dynamically update getChildCount() from Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to update a RecyclerView with information from Firebase. I've successfully been able to update the TextViews in my view from Firebase but, in doing so, my current code won't update the getChildCount() of the RecyclerView with the amount of children from the database without infinitely looping.

My current code: (CardAdapter.java)

```
public int getChildCount() {
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mReference = mDatabase.getReference();
        final String userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snap :
                        dataSnapshot.child("pet").child("users").child(userID).getChildren()) {
                    mChildCount = (int) snap.getChildrenCount();
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        };
        mReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
        return mChildCount;
    }
```

This code works, but it infinitely loops due to the notifyDataSetChanged(); method that updates the RecyclerView.

What can I do to make it so the RecyclerView getChildCount() is dynamically updated from Firebase without infinitely looping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not place your code to acquire data inside `getChildrenCount()`. I myself, usually place that in my `Activity` or inside constructor of `Adapter`. Like this:

```
public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<YourObject> yourObjectList;

    public YourAdapter() {
        ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.child("pet").child("users").child(userID).getChildren()) {
                    ...
                    // add to list
                    yourObjectList.add(snap.getValue(YourObject));
                    ...
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        };
        mReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(YourAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        YourObject yourObject = yourObjectList.get(position);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return yourObjectList.size();
    }
}
```

Hope this help.